# Can I complete Head of State if I completed Take It Back! while the slaves were on their way? (Broken Steel installed)

Tags: fallout-3

Just before going on with the Liberty Prime attack on the purifier, I did part of the Head of State quest, killing the slavers at the Lincoln Memorial and setting the slaves from the Temple of the Union on their way.

I know they take a couple of days to get to the Memorial, so in order to "kill time" I completed the Take It Back! quest in the meanwhile...

I have Broken Steel installed, so I can continue playing, but when I go to the Memorial, the slaves are not there yet, even though a couple of weeks are supposed to have passed.

Is there any way to complete the Head of State quest?

Comment: have you checked back at the temple of union?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a huge pain, but have you walked the route the slaves take from the Temple of the Union to the Lincoln Memorial? The NPCs have been known to get caught on terrain glitches. Sometimes, interacting with one of them can resolve the issue.

I'm kind of worried that the slaves actually did arrive, but "timed out" while waiting for you to tell them it was safe to head up to the Memorial. I don't think there's a way to conclusively prove or disprove this theory, unfortunately.